# Cforms II wordpress plugin display in popup in widget area

Tags: wordpress, popup

I am unable to display cforms II in lightbox in sidebar. Is there any way to display cforms II in lightbox?

I found this code to display in pages but it is not working in widget area.

```
[formlightbox text="some text"]
<!--cforms name="Call Me Back"-->
[/formlightbox]
```

even i used this code in page. popup displaying but cforms not displaying

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[formlightbox text="some text"]<!--cforms name="Call Me Back"--> [/formlightbox]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

me too trying to get t done with the form lightbox plugin, first, the shortcode you are using doesn't support any more so visit plugin author website for updated shortcode that works with new version 1.1.2, i m using this shortcode

> [formlightbox_call title="FORM NAME" class="1362370254262"]FORM NAME[/formlightbox_call]
>   [formlightbox_obj id="1362370254262" style="" onload="false"][/formlightbox_obj]

but the result is nothing show in lightbox....any idea guys?????

Comment: Your answer is more a comment for me. Please, next time you want to add something on the question do it with the comment.